# How to get values of edittext which is in fragment on button click which is in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

[signup screen with of two different modules driver and customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lusRg.png)

Hi everyone I am working in `android` from past one year but now I am creating an app in which am using `fragments` instead of `activity` even after serching from so many sites and blogs am unable to implement what I want.

My requirement is as you see on the image two `radio button` one for customer and one for driver so when user click on any one of options then signup screen appears which is on fragment and one button is there at bottom which is on `activity` so I want how to get all `edittext` value on button click so that i can send these values to the server. My main problem is getting the values of `edittext` fields on button click.
So any help will be appriciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: Basically just follow this from one Fragment to the activity, don't worry about the other Fragment. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Try this when onClick u can get the current fragment from fragment manager write a method in fragment which gives all the values of that screen take it in activity and send that to server. I'm not sure it'll work in your context. But try it once

Comment: @Raghavendra i tried same approach earlier but it won't work for me

Comment: Can u post the code what u have tried.? And what error u faced?

Comment: Use _interface_ for it

Comment: Create `getEditTextValue()` function in your `Fragment`. Then when `onClick`  , you can call `yourFragment.getEditTextValue()` to get user input.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment      
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);              
            this.initViews(rootView);
    selectProfessionsTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        whta_you_want_on_button_click();
                    }
                });
           }

     private void initViews(View view) {
          //define your edittext like  FirstNameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.FirstNameEditText);

    }
```

now define the  `whta_you_want_on_button_click()` method

Answer (score 0):

in your activity, put below code in your button's click event.

```
    try {
        Fragment rg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YourFragmentTag");
        if (rg != null) {

            EditText et = (EditText) ((YourFragment) rg).getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            String etValue = et.getText().toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context will change from `getApplicationContext()` to `getActivity.getApplicationContext()` when you are referencing a fragment instead of an activity
You have to create your edittext in this fashion
While assigning the layout you need to assign in this way.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout,container,false);
```

And while assigning edittext you need to take it as below

```
EditText edt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.yourid);
String str = edt.getText().toString();
```

So on button click you can get the edittext string easily from onClick method with above code.

Comment: My **button is in activity not in fragment** i have to get edittext value through button

Answer (score 0):

You can use static keyword make all edittext static so you will get all edittext values in activity on button click.

in your fragment suppose MyFragment.java

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

 View rootView;
 public static EditText edt;

    public MyFragment() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    init();
    return rootView;
    }

    protected void init(){
    edt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt);
    }

 }
```

in your activity suppose MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{
   Button start;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button) findViewByid(R.id.button);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          try{
          String value = MyFragment.edt.getText().toString().trim();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }catch(Exception e){} 

        }
    });

   }

 }
```